# iptables exception

Tags: linux, iptables

If my iptables is set to drop packets from certain hosts, is it possible to add a host that can be excepted from this if it is affected?

The hostname I'm wanting to except from these rules is affected by them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to use an ACCEPT rule for this host before the DROP rules you want to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Rules are evaluated in order, so just make sure that your accept rule comes before the default deny rule.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be useful in this case, but the default policy(last evaluated rule) can also be changed with the -P ACCEPT.